# add an element to 2d list using dart with add() method

Tags: dart

the normal list in dart 1d can use with it many methods like insert remove indexOf etc . but in 2d list many of list methods can't work with it ? why an example below

```
var lista = [1,2,3,4,5] ; 
lista.add(6);
print(lista);
```

**Works fine**

```
var listb = [[1,2,3],
[4,5]
];
```

`listb.add(6);` // wont add cause the argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.
accept it only when listb.add([6]); but add this as new element in list i want to add in [4,5] a number only ?!

Comment: You need to get a reference to the inner list that you want to append to, e.g.: `listb[1].add(6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add to the second list of the lists, just do so:

```
void main() {
  var listb = [[1,2,3], [4,5]];
  
  listb[1].add(6);
  
  print(listb);
}
```

This prints

> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

You wanted the first list to know that you want to add to the second of it's elements. That is not how programming works, the compiler does not guess what you may want. You have to explicitly tell it what to do.